# Error Msg 206, Niveau 16, État 2, Ligne 91 Conflit de types d'opérandes : date est incompatible avec tinyint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, where-clause

I am getting an error:

> Error Msg 206, Niveau 16, État 2, Ligne 91
> Conflit de types d'opérandes : date est incompatible avec tinyint

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation 
(
    codres int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    numcl int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES client ,
    numt int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES typesejour,
    codho int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES hotel,
    datedebut date,
    datefin date,
    montant float DEFAULT 0,

    CONSTRAINT ck CHECK (datefin > datedebut)
)

ALTER TABLE reservation 
    ADD CONSTRAINT ch1 DEFAULT 0 FOR montant;

UPDATE reservation 
SET montant = 0.9 * montant
WHERE MONTH(datedebut) IN (9, 10) 
  AND (datefin) IN (9, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the `where` clause of your `update` statement:

```
where month(datedebut) in (9,10) and (datefin) in (9,10)
```

The second condition raises the error, since you are trying to compare a `date` (`datefin`) against a list of integer values (`9` and `10`).

Presumably, you meant:

```
where month(datedebut) in (9,10) and month(datefin) in (9,10)
```

Note that comparing dates like this is highly inefficient. It is much better to use direct date comparisons whenever possible. Assuming that you want September and October of last year, you would write this:

```
where 
        datedebut >= '20190901'
    and datedebut <  '20191101'
    and datefin   >= '20190901'
    and datefin   <  '20191101'
```

Of course, if you want September and October of *any year*, then your expression is the right way to go.

Comment: additional information: 20190901 corresponds to YYYYMMDD , of ISO8601 . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601